# CSS4 Tag - Misnomer or Useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I created a tag named [css4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css4), under the impression that CSS4 was the appropriate abbreviation for CSS Level 4 modules that are currently being implemented into modern browsers. Immediately after doing so, I stumbled upon a resource that suggested that there is no such thing as "CSS4," and that there never will be.

#### Excerpt from [*A Word About CSS4*](https://www.xanthir.com/b4Ko0):

> There has never been a CSS4. There will never be a CSS4. CSS4 is not a thing that exists.
>
> The term "CSS3" refers to everything published after CSS 2.1.
> CSS is on its last version *as a language as a whole*, so it would be appropriate to just drop the number entirely and refer to everything from now on as just "CSS".

However, a quick Google search of "CSS4" returns a full page of results [such as this one](https://css4-selectors.com/) referring to the new features in the Level 4 modules, so while it may be technically correct that there is no true "CSS4," it seems to be a popular abbreviation for CSS Level 4 modules.

I think Wikipedia makes a good, unbiased explanation of the situation, so I'll include that here for reference.

#### Excerpt from [*Wikipedia's Cascading Stylesheet Sheets article*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_4):

> There is no single, integrated CSS4 specification, since it is split into separate modules. However, there are "level 4" modules.
>
> Since CSS3 split the CSS language's definition into modules, the modules have been allowed to level independently. Most modules are level 3 - they build on things from CSS 2.1. A few level 4 modules exist (such as Image Values, Backgrounds & Borders, or Selectors), which build on the functionality of a preceding level 3 module. Others define entirely new functionality, such as Flexbox.
>
> So, while no monolithic CSS4 will be worked on after CSS3 is finished completely, the level 4 modules can collectively be referred to as CSS4.

So after reading all of this, I've been going back-and-forth about the usefulness of a "CSS4" tag. On one hand, it's technically inaccurate to call CSS Level 4 modules CSS4, but on the other hand it is a popular abbreviation for it.

As these features become available in browsers, I'm sure many people will have questions about them, so having a tag for them seems prudent, but I leave it up to Meta to decide the future of such a tag!

Comment: Never opt for common populism over technical correctness while you still have the choice. That's how societies degrade.

Comment: @ZeroRequiem Numquam optet rectitudo communis populism super technica dum est electio . Fuerunt autem qui in societatibus proicimus.

Comment: @Yakk [tag:cv-pls] [StackExchange should be in English](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) :P

Comment: @ssube: You do realize that's merely a translation of the preceding comment, right?  One doesn't need to know Latin (well) to get the joke.

Comment: @ssube also, your link links to "non-English **question** policy". From what I see this is a comment. And it's also quite funny.

Comment: @BenVoigt Alas, my subtly doth betray me. I merely desired to ironically direct Yakk to our official standard of plebian-ism.

Comment: Always opt for common populism over technical correctness while you still have the choice. That's how technology improves.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Technology does not improve by being incorrect.

Comment: Who would have thought that CSS' specification could be as effed up as CSS is.

Answer (score 25):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637901/is-css3-an-official-standard) for an elaboration on the first source that you quoted. Note that I take the first source as authoritative because it's written by a member of the CSSWG.

I can see how "CSS4" may be a popular abbreviation for "CSS level 4 module"; however, the problem with *collectively* referring to all level 4 modules as "CSS4" or "CSS level 4" becomes clear when you consider the fact that CSS3 (or "CSS level 3", according to [its proper definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#css3)) brings about completely new modules, such as Flexbox, Animations, Transforms, Transitions, Grid Layout, and Variables, that all start at level 1, yet are still (correctly) referred to as "CSS3".

The reason they all start at level 1 is because the features described are completely new to CSS, rather than extending existing CSS2.1 features. But, obviously, the next level after 1 is 2, not 4. Would these level 2 modules be considered "CSS4" modules as well, or not? What about the eventual level 3 and 4 revisions of those modules? It seems nobody among authors has thought of these things because it's never come up in real-world discussion outside of WG meetings. This could potentially be super confusing in tags when the time comes that people begin asking questions about these new features.

The "most right" thing to do that I can think of is to make [css4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css4) a synonym of [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3)<sup>1</sup>, since essentially any new module past the original CSS2.1 standard, no matter what its level number is, is part of the collective CSS3 standard. Attempting to use [css4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css4) in a question would simply have it silently and painlessly changed to [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) without any major consequences, except more people being educated on what each term properly refers to (and does not refer to).

Besides, in the grand scheme of things it's not the level number that matters, but [browser implementations that decide which features are specced in which modules](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Process/#implementation-experience). Having any distinction beyond "CSS3" is unnecessary and would only serve to confuse readers.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>There's actually already a debate going on about whether [css3] should even exist separately from [css], although there hasn't been a proper meta thread on this yet so I'm not going to go into that here.</sub>

Comment: Those same reasons have always made me confused why we need a CSS3 tag, though. We already have specific tags like [tag:css-animations], [tag:css-transitions], [tag:css-transforms], and the like for the *specific*, more complex features of CSS. And pretty much everything else that CSS3 "added" is so incredibly simple that having its own separate tag becomes meaningless.

Comment: @animuson: Yeah. I'm less concerned with it mostly because "CSS3" is well-defined - the only problem is the misuse of the tag. But like I said, good fodder for a separate thread ;)

Answer (score 10):

Well, the masses who used them never understood what "mp3" files were named for. We call the place where we plug in the network cable a "RJ-45", and 9 pin serial connectors were commonly called DB-9. Many things were immediately popularly called the incorrect (official) name because the natural language evolution evokes an obvious name that is immediatly understood and commonly spontaneously used upon first needing to refer to this new thing.

People *will* try using a tag of css4. If that's rejected, they won't know what it should be. So make it automatic: css4 is a synonym that's automatically shown as css-level-4.

Comment: Interesting compromise, but one wonders what might happen when CSS Transforms 2 arrives (and it's shaping up to be one of the first new level 2 modules to hit implementations in the next *year* alone).

Comment: @BoltClock, I guess we'll need a whole dedicated SE just for CSS, in order to organize it all and educate the suppliants so they can learn the right way to approach the adept with their questions first.

Comment: I'd totally be on board with that.

Comment: Google's top hits for "CSS4" are *interesting*… http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/css4-is-coming-what-you-need-to-know--webdesign-11521  Good ideas for how to answer people too clueless to even know what they're saying.

Answer (score 5):

## I've gone ahead and removed the [css4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css4) tag from the question

So yeah, today I discovered that this tag existed and my first instinct was to remove the tag from that question. I then had a search here on meta to see if there had been any discussion about CSS4.

#### Why?

Almost 3 months on and [that question you answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506735/what-does-i-mean-in-a-css-attribute-selector) is the only one using the [css4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css4) tag.

[image: CSS4 Tag]

Furthermore, the question was already appropriately tagged as [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors), whose wiki has, since 2013 stated:

> **Future Implementations:**
>
> - [W3C CSS Selectors Level 4 Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/)

*In fact, [it was I](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3204315) who added that in there - bit of a coincidence that I find myself here a year and a half on!*

I think the [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors) tag alone suitably covers level 4 selectors which, after all, is the reason you added the [css4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css4) tag in the first place.