# When is the [css3] tag appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags

I frequent the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag often and many questions are tagged both with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3).

Leaving aside other common mistags ([html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) on a generic [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) question etc), when is appropriate to retag a [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) question to simply [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)?

Should [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) be used only for questions regarding problems with functionality added by CSS3 specifically?
The list [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS3) includes, but is not limited to:

- opacity & rgba
- numerous pseudoclasses (`:enabled`; `:disabled`; `:checked` etc)
- media queries
- new values to existing properties (`background-attachment: local` etc)

and many more.

Comment: I know [at least a handful of us agree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/css4-tag-misnomer-or-useful#comment155332_286089) that the [css3] tag itself is starting to become quite meaningless. These days, it's more appropriate to describe CSS3 as "any CSS standard apart from CSS2" than as a list of specific features. In other words, post-CSS2 CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for that link, haven't seen that question before. And to be honest, it was your profile that led me to ask this very question. So what practical value does [css3] have at all given the above discussion?

Comment: There's some practical value in *loosely* categorizing questions asking about new CSS features, or questions that accept answers making use of new features without having to worry about browser support. In the past decade or so there has been a very clearly-defined gap in browser support for the majority of features, but but as CSS continues to grow and features continue to be implemented in an iterative process, that gap has since been reduced to nothing more than a blur.

Comment: If a question isn't necessarily "CSS3-specific" in that sense, that's when I retag it to [css].

Comment: Follow-up: What about tags like `ruby-on-rails-4` and 3? Rails2 tag still exists, and there are sub-versions of Rails 3.1/3.2 tags. I know there is still a disparity since many apps use Rails3, but nevertheless, just a thought.

Comment: @HunterStevens I think that discussion doesn't really relate that much, since CSS isn't something where you generally use a specific version.

Answer (score 35):

I don't see a benefit to the [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) tag at all.  My recommendation would be to turn [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) into a synonym of [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).

- There's no way to validate against a specific "version" like there is with HTML:  it is either valid or it isn't.
- If the user has specific requirements regarding CSS, knowing the target browsers (eg. IE8+, Android 2.3, etc.) is more helpful than simply knowing "anything from CSS3 is perfectly fine".
- No one is going to turn their nose up at a solution that comes from a "version" prior to CSS3 (just look at how long negative text-indent for image replacement has stuck around, it's less verbose than more modern techniques despite having worse performance in certain browsers).
- Most people don't know what counts as CSS3 anyway (I don't, and I've been doing this for years).
- We have questions that get tagged [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) but not [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) (which is rather annoying when it comes to closing duplicates for those of us with the css badge, but not the css3 badge).
- I can't think of anything that was part of CSS2 that isn't also part of CSS3 (and often we need to provide both old and new techniques to maximize browser support in cases where the new technique offers a better experience:  `display: inline-block` for flex items in browsers that don't support Flexbox)

The current practice of adding tags based off of CSS modules (Flexbox, Animations, etc.) makes more sense than keeping around a tag for CSS3.

Comment: "Most people don't know what counts as CSS3 anyway" I do, and I can say with confidence that it's becoming irrelevant (as noted in the comments above).

Comment: For posterity, [here is a list of all the users with a gold \[css\] badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/247/css), and [all the users with a gold \[css3\] badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2140/css3). Hint: not all gold tag badge holders make a habit of exercising their privileges.

Comment: @BoltClock can this [discussion] + [tag] be upgraded to a [feature-request] + [synonym-request]?

Comment: @Braiam: That would change the meaning of the question completely and require possibly a rewrite.

Comment: @BoltClock I wan't speaking about editing this question, but that the issue in discussion is raised to a synonym request.

Comment: @Braiam: A synonym request was already raised [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/can-we-please-make-css3-a-synonym-of-css) but I assume there was no agreement on getting that done.

Comment: @Harry 12 months ago, yet it seems to come back to haunt us. Mayhap another request would be taken differently.

Comment: "*I can't think of anything that was part of CSS2 that isn't also part of CSS3*": CSS2 has the [`clip`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#clipping) property, which is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/#clip-property) in CSS Masking.

Comment: There are many CSS modules that deprecate various CSS2 features. As another example, Selectors 4 deprecates single-colon pseudo-element syntax (as I [answered @Oriol's question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684797/should-i-use-single-colons-or-double-colons-for-before-after-first-le/28527928#28527928) recently). Although UAs are required to support the legacy syntax for the sake of compatibility, authors are encouraged to avoid them.

Answer (score 8):

I think [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) are more and more becoming the same as the new features/properties introduced in css3 are becoming standardized.

Version specific tags, in my opinion, are only really useful when the versions are different enough to require different answers.

That said, I'm not sure that css3 has been standardized enough to warrant folding it into the css tag. There are still enough caveats and corner cases that need specific knowledge of the css3 spec and knowledge of how different browsers have implemented the new properties/features.

As far as re-tagging goes, its probably wasted effort. Nowadays most people who are proficient in css are also familiar enough with css3 to be able to answer both. If you organically stumble upon a question about something like `background-color` that has the css3 tag feel free to remove it, but going on a re-tagging spree will just end up bumping a lot of questions to the front page that don't really need the added attention.

Comment: But, you see, more and more CSS3 specifications are being added every day. It's a living standard, much like WHATWG's vision of HTML. And, unlike CSS2, it's not a single monolithic specification with a finite number of sections. Unless they radicalize the language as we know it or stop developing it altogether, CSS3 will never be "complete".

Comment: That being said, your first paragraph would certainly hold true - for those who define "css" as anything that's been standardized and widely implemented.

Answer (score -2):

Hi guys i am not such export to comment on this big one

- and yes i also agree with you guys that now a days we all familiar with the css terms and more of the people can't judge the difference in CSS and CSS3 even including me.
- one measurement which is introduced by CSS3 or css i don't knw, but i am really been fan of it and try to exploring the best use of the current design trends that is **"vw"** and **"vh"**
  here i would like to share a link with you

**http://www.tipue.com/blog/css3-vw-vh/**

now come to the css tag i was just searching and found a nice article about the comparison between both of them that is bellowed given link

**http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/css3-vs-css-a-speed-benchmark/**

eager to know about much more for css3 yes i know that it's about what it is ? the question is that only because of that we haven't familiar that much of css3 or browser incompatibilities with css3 else we are too much familiar with css only. i don't know the actual reason yet just need to explore this.

Comment: That second link. Who in their right mind would think a "performance comparison" between "CSS3 and CSS" makes sense?!

Comment: For that matter, I don't understand what the point of this answer is. Are you trying to answer the question, or are you just thinking aloud?